# Проблемма при построение Dagger2

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger2, inversion-of-control

Пытаюсь ставить clean architor

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.testclean3.Presentation.UndeMainPresentation.GetCorework(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Вот это получаю, при обращении к undeMainPresentation.GetCorework(Ss);:

```
   public class MainPresntation {

    @Inject UndeMainPresentation undeMainPresentation;


    public MainPresntation()
    {
       // this.undeMainPresentation=  ApplicationComponent.getUndeMainPresentation();


        AndroidApplication.applicationComponent.inject(this);
    }

    public void MakeControl(String Ss)
    {
         undeMainPresentation.GetCorework(Ss);
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public MainPresntation mainPresntation;
    private ApplicationComponent applicationComponent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        this.applicationComponent= AndroidApplication.getApplicationComponent();




        this.mainPresntation=new MainPresntation();
    }

    public void OnClick(View V)
    {
        mainPresntation.MakeControl("wefefwfwe");
    }
}
```

ApplicationModule:

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule
{
    private final Application application;

    public ApplicationModule
            (Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }
   @Provides @Singleton Context provideApplicationContext() {
       return this.application;
   }
    @Provides @Singleton ThreadExecutor provideThreadExecutor(JobExecutor jobExecutor) {
        return jobExecutor;
    }
    @Provides @Singleton PostExecutionThread providePostExecutionThread(UIThread uiThread) {
        return uiThread;
    }
     @Provides
     Repositor provideRepositor(Repositor repositor) {
         return repositor;

     }
     @Provides
     WorkDomain provideWorkDomain(WorkDomain workDomain) {
         return workDomain;
     }
 @Provides
 UndeMainPresentation prvideUndeMainPresentation(UndeMainPresentation undeMainPresentation)
 {
     return undeMainPresentation;
 }
}
```

ApplicationComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);

    Context context();
    ThreadExecutor threadExecutor();
    PostExecutionThread postExecutionThread();


    void inject(UndeMainPresentation undeMainPresentation);
    void inject(Repositor repositor);
    void inject(WorkDomain workDomain);
    void inject(MainPresntation mainPresntation);


}
```

И напоследок :

```
public class UndeMainPresentation {


    private WorkDomain workDomain;

    @Inject public UndeMainPresentation(WorkDomain workDomain)
    {
        this.workDomain = workDomain;
    }

    public void GetCorework(String sss)
    {
        workDomain.execute(new UserListObserver(),null);
    }


    private final class UserListObserver extends DefaultObserver<Data_Work> {

        @Override public void onComplete() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Data_Work data_work) {

        }

        @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }


    }
}
```

В чем Я ошибаюсь?

P.S. 
AndroidApplication, но уже переделанном виде , а не такой какой был в момент создания вопроса:

```
  public class AndroidApplication  extends Application {

    private static ApplicationComponent applicationComponent;

    public static UndeMainPresentation undeMainPresentation;


    @Override public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        this.applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
                .build();

        applicationComponent.inject(undeMainPresentation);

    }
    public static ApplicationComponent getApplicationComponent()
    {
        return applicationComponent;
    }


    public static   UndeMainPresentation getUndeMainPresentation()
    {
        return undeMainPresentation;
    }


}
```

P.S.S
Класс AndroidApplication находиться в папке Dagger2
Манифест приложения:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testclean3">

    <application
        android:name=".Dagger2.AndroidApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Вы не делаете инъекцию в MainPresntation. И не сможете, т.к. для ApplicationModule вам контекст нужен. Сделайте так: ApplicationModule инициалиируйте в Application классе, не в активити. В Application же классе сделайте статическое поле для получения модуля. Тогда вы сможете получить модуль в MainPresntation и сделать инъекцию.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб "Тогда вы сможете получить модуль в MainPresntation и сделать инъекцию" - вы имеете в виду сделать в MainPresntation конструктор , принимающий UndeMainPresentation? Не совсем понимаю, что тут нужно сделать)

Comment: Можно по разному. Если хотите использовать инъекцию через конструктор, то надо сделать Provides методы в модуле для всех аргументов конструктора. В вашем случае для UndeMainPresentation.Тогда оно автоматически всё прибудет в экземпляр класса через конструктор, если он будет помечен аннотацией Inject при создании экземпляра класса MainPresntation в активити. Либо вам надо опять таки Provides метод для UndeMainPresentation и сделать moduleInstance.inject(this) в MainPresntation

Comment: @ЮрийСПб решил взять второй ваш метод , но на  moduleInstance.inject(this)  немного ругается) Может вы имели в виду ApplicationComponent ?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Provides-метод сделал в ApplicationModule для UndeMainPresentation...

Comment: Да, надо ApplicationComponent использовать. И его из Application класса отдавать. И в нём сделать `inject` метод.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Сделал метод inject(MainPresentation mainPresentation) в ApplicationComponent  и  добавил в коснтруктор класса  MainPresentation : ApplicationComponent.inject(this). Ругается что inject не статичен)

Comment: Вам надо получить экземпляр класса компонента. Смотрите первый комментарий мой.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Так конструктор MainPresntation() теперь получил this.undeMainPresentation=AndroidApplication.getUndeMainPresentation();  а AndroidApplication  получил статичный метод     public static   UndeMainPresentation getUndeMainPresentation()
    {
        return undeMainPresentation;
    } ,  а его конструктор applicationComponent.inject(undeMainPresentation);  И оно все равно не работает ... Может дело в  WorkDomain ?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Пока откручу WorkDomain- для тестов

Comment: @ЮрийСПб и оно не взлетело)

Comment: не, должно быть не так) 1. Создать класс-наследник Application. 2. Создать статическую публичную переменную для компонента даггера в классе-наследнике Application. 3. В его onCreate методе создать компонент даггера и присвоить его в качестве значения для переменной из п2.  4. Прописать класс из п1 в манифесте приложения. 5. В классе, где надо сделать инъекцию получите экземпляр компонента из класса из п1 из переменной из п2. 6. Теперь переменные с аннотацией Inject получат значение, которое вы в модуле возвращаете из метода с Provides аннотацией.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  Так а как получить экземпляр компонента из класса-наследника Application ?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Сделал публичным ApplicationComponent  и перенес          AndroidApplication.applicationComponent.inject(this.undeMainPresentation); в MainPresentation (в конструктор класс), но оно все ещё падает

Comment: Надо в inject передавать не то, что вы хотите получить, а то, где это что-то надо получить. Т.е. вам надо всегда в inject метод передавать `this`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб     AndroidApplication.applicationComponent.inject(this)  в MainPresentation сделал , но получил : error: [Dagger/DependencyCycle] Found a dependency cycle:
com.example.testclean3.Presentation.UndeMainPresentation is injected at com.example.testclean3.Dagger2.ApplicationModule.prvideUndeMainPresentation(undeMainPresentation)

Comment: Покажите актуальный код в вопросе. Похоже, что вы пытаетесь одно и то же 2 раза разными способами заинжектить. prvideUndeMainPresentation(undeMainPresentation), скорее всего, вам надо без агрумента делать. А то у вас он сам в себя инъжектится.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил код в вопросе

Comment: Замените метод prvideUndeMainPresentation на вот такое: `@Provides
 UndeMainPresentation prvideUndeMainPresentation(WorkDomain workDomain )
 {
     return new UndeMainPresentation(workDomain);
 }` Ну и метод provideWorkDomain надо изменить. Типа так, наверное: `@Provides
     WorkDomain provideWorkDomain() { return new WorkDomain (); }`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо вам большое- да ошибка была ещё в этих @Provides)) Оно внезапно взлетело)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб НО! Из-за особенности Domain   нужно:    Provides
     WorkDomain provideWorkDomain(Repositor repositor,JobExecutor jobExecutor,UIThread uiThread) {
        return new WorkDomain(repositor,jobExecutor,uiThread) ;
    }

Comment: Пожалуйста) Главное тут принцип понять. Provides методы должны возвращать экземпляры классов, которые потом вы будете с `Inject` аннотацией получать путём вызова `component.inject()` или использовать в конструкторах с такой же аннотацией.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб понять как раз сложновато чето)) Аа ответ оформите- пускай вопрос без ответа не висит)

Comment: Ох, долго ответ писать... По хорошему надо там всю теорию DI излагать, а это муторно) Можете сами написать)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб А как быть, если нужно (хочется) инжектить в к слассы, которые находятся в стороне от mvp и контекста. Обращаясь в application за конмпонентой мы привязываемя к контексту, который есть в модуле и размазываем его вообще по всему приложени. Сделать над application компонент еще более высокого уровня без контекста не получается. Как будто дагер не приспособлен под трехуровневую вложенность компонентов. Я в тупике.

Comment: Из application можно обратитсья к компоненту не делаея его статичным: `MyApp.get(this).getComponent()`, где `get() {return (MyApp) context.getApplicationContext()}`